# Can you scp a device file?

Tags: devices, scp, block-device, flash-memory

My flash is partitioned as /dev/mtd0 /dev/mtd1 etc....And I want to scp one of the partitions over to my pc so I can analyze it with a hex editor, but everytime I try to copy it with scp I get -not a regular file. How can I scp the contents of a flash partition? I think I did it once with WinSCP on a windows machine but it only worked for small partitions of < 10mb and anything bigger would disconnect from the device.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A combination of `dd` and `ssh` can probably help here:

```
# dd if=/dev/mtd0 | ssh me@myhost "dd of=mtd0.img"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into trouble `dd`ing a large block device over ssh, but `cat` did the trick for me:

```
sudo cat /dev/mmcblk1p3 | ssh me@myhost 'cat >mmcblk1p3'
```